# Insert Duplicate entry in mysql

Tags: mysql

Need to insert same Date of Birth for Different person. Ie. I have created a web page where student registers. in MySQL I have created DOB field and if any student with same dob inserted it tells Duplicate entry and record is not inserted. i need to insert the record for DOB

```
INSERT INTO `degree` (`Candidate`, `Father`, `Course`, `Year`, `DOB`, `Roll`)
VALUES ('AAAA\r\n', 'AAAAA\r\n', 'AAA', '2199', '1933-06-21', 'AAAAAAA')
```

MySQL said:

> Documentation
>
> #1062 - Duplicate entry '1933-06-21' for key 'DOB'

Comment: Don't make the DOB field a key.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the result of `SHOW CREATE TABLE degree`.

Comment: You need to post the structure of the `degree` table. From what I see, DOB is some key, you need to change that.

Comment: Make it a key. Just don't make it unique.

Answer (score 3):

You have a unique key on the DOB field that needs to be removed.

Find the name of the index in the output of

```
show create table degree
```

and then remove the unique key with:

```
alter table degree drop index NAME_OF_INDEX
```

There's a good chance you still want an index on the field, just not a unique one in which case you can re-add it wth

```
alter table degree add index (DOB)
```